# Moment.js is giving incostintent format responses

Tags: javascript, time, momentjs

I have two moment objects:

```
> calEvent.start
Moment {_isAMomentObject: true, _i: "2015-06-11T11:00:00", _f: "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss", _isUTC: false, _pf: Object…}_ambigTime: false_ambigZone: false_d: Thu Jun 11 2015 11:00:00 GMT+0300 (EEST)_f: "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss"_fullCalendar: true_i: "2015-06-11T11:00:00"_isAMomentObject: true_isUTC: false_isValid: true_locale: f_offset: 0_pf: Object__proto__: Moment

> dateTime.startDT
Moment {_isAMomentObject: true, _i: "Th, 11-06-2015 11:00", _f: "dd, DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm", _isUTC: false, _pf: Object…}_d: Thu Jun 11 2015 11:00:00 GMT+0300 (EEST)_f: "dd, DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm"_i: "Th, 11-06-2015 11:00"_isAMomentObject: true_isUTC: false_isValid: true_locale: Object_pf: Object__proto__: Moment
```

When i'm formatting that two moment objects with same string it gives different responses:

```
> calEvent.start.format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm')
"2015-06-11A11:00"
           ^
           A? what is that? i was expecting 'T'

> dateTime.startDT.format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm')
"2015-06-11T11:00"
           ^
           This is correct one for me.
```

I tried to findout what is different between that objects and why moment.js is converting T to A.

Comment: Do you have JSFiddle that reproduces? I made this and it seems to be working. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cn78jyaw/)

Comment: i can create but that moment objects are created by different calendar events. may be i can dump them to json to use.

Comment: That would be helpful. You can also update my JSFiddle if you see something wrong with how I'm setting the dates.

Comment: but where is the date coming fro ?